# XStream Implicit Collection Configuration Issue

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I'm working with a system that generates this type of XML:

```
<address>
  <addressLine>123 Main Street</addressLine>
  <addressLine>Suite 123</addressLine>
  <city>Test City</city>
  <stateOrProvince>AA</stateOrProvince>
  <postalCode>00000</postalCode>
</address>
```

The two addressLine elements should be part of an XStream implicit collection - I'd like to call a `getAddressLine()` method and get a `List<String>` output.

I've been working with XStream's tutorial and haven't quite figured out how to get the `addressLine` elements to map correctly. There's a similar use case in [XStream's Tweaking Output tutorial](http://x-stream.github.io/manual-tweaking-output.html), but no example code is provided:

> Another use case are collections, arrays and maps. If a class has a
>   field that is a one of those types, by default all of its elements are
>   embedded in an element that represents the container object itself. By
>   configuring the XStream with the `XStream.addImplicitCollection()`,
>   `XStream.addImplicitArray()`, and `XStream.addImplicitMap()` methods it is
>   possible to keep the elements directly as child of the class and the
>   surrounding tag for the container object is omitted. It is even
>   possible to declare more than one implicit collection, array or map
>   for a class, but the elements must then be distinguishable to populate
>   the different containers correctly at deserialization.
>
> In the following example the Java type representing the farm may have
>   two containers, one for cats and one for dogs:
>
> ```
> <farm>
>   <cat>Garfield</cat>
>   <cat>Arlene</cat>
>   <cat>Nermal</cat>
>   <dog>Odie</dog>
> </farm>
> ```

However, this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8105729/897491) suggests that the XStream farm example is not possible.

I've tried this Java code to unit test my Java code, but no luck yet:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());        
xstream.alias("address", Address.class);
xstream.alias("addressLine", String.class);     
xstream.addImplicitCollection(Address.class, "addressLines");       

Address address = (Address) xstream.fromXML( 
    new FileInputStream("src/test/resources/addressTest.xml"));
```

Are there any other configuration changes I should try?

Note: I'm currently using XStream v1.2.2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, if possible you should upgrade to a more recent XStream - 1.2.2 was released in 2007.  But to answer your question, try:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
xstream.alias("address", Address.class);
xstream.addImplicitCollection(Address.class, "addressLines", "addressLine", String.class);
```

This says treat all elements with the name `addressLine` as Strings, and gather them into the `addressLines` collection (i.e. `someAddress.getAddressLines()`).

Comment: Agreed - currently stuck using the older version due to the approval process of the dev team I'm working with. Thanks - got my test to work using a variation of what you suggested:
`xstream.addImplicitCollection(Address.class, "addressLine", String.class);`

Comment: I am so happy to have run across this answer.  This will help me a lot.  Thanks.

Comment: This finally got me where I needed to be.  I was a little thrown by the values of the parameters in the addImplicitCollection call, addressLines vs addressLine, but finally realized that you said the 2nd param was the collection name (as in the Java code) and that the 3rd param was the XML element that would be stored in said collection.  That last sentence in your answer was the entire answer for me....thanks.